# Android - onRequestPermissionsResult dosen't wait user's input in Android 12(API 31)

Tags: android

My application request GPS permission, must wait user's input.

In Android 7.1(API 25) onRequestPermissionsResult called after user's input.

But in Android 12(API 31) onRequestPermissionsResult called before user's input.

Check permission code.

```
final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1981;
private final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]
        {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
        }; // permission list
        
//...

// onclick login button
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
{
    boolean permission = isPermissionGranted(); // check permission is granted
    if (!permission)
        setGpsPermission(); // request login when permission is not granted.
    else // start login when permission is granted.
    {
        gpsOn = true;
        startLogin();
    }
}
```

Request permission code.

```
private boolean isPermissionGranted()
{
    for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
        if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            continue;
        }
        final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);

        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != result) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private void setGpsPermission()
{
    // request permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST); 
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) // in Android 12(API 31), grantResults always -1, -1, -1
    {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST :
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                gpsOn = true;
                startLogin();
            }
            else
            {
                gpsOn = false;
                startLogin(); 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

When I debugged, Android 7.1(API 25) is wait util user's input, but Android 12(API 31) is not wait, so grantResults always {-1, -1, -1}.

Why it works different?

How can I make Android 12(API 31) work like Android 7.1(API 25) that wait user's input?

Comment: `isPermissionGranted(); ` Which permission? You are requesting three. Which from the three?

Comment: You should not request coarse and fine location at the same time.

Comment: check `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in `isPermissionGranted`

Comment: when remove `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission,  Android 12(API31) wait user's input. why?

Comment: You should not request coarse and fine location at the same time.

Comment: @blackapps
  Oh, I get it.. background_location policy changed after Android 10, Thank for your help!